# ImportError when haystack is added to urls?

Tags: python, django, templates, tags, django-haystack

When I add the following to my site.urls.py file

```
#haystack search
url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

I get this error

```
Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named urls
```

here

```
a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.logout %}">Logout</a>
```

or at the first location of the {% url %} tag, when I comment out the haystack url part, the site works fine.

I'm using python2.7, django1.3, and haystack 1.2.4

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I tried the same setup on a template file without {% urls %} but still get the No module named urls error.  I used easy_install django-haystack, added it to my installed_apps, create a HAYSTACK_SITECONF file and its path in settings.py, why is there no urls for haystack?

Thanks!

No sure what happened but I had to go the the python2.7 folder and rm -rf the haystack folders and pip install them again... and it worked... :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the template code and look at the traceback. I've had a few problems where it shows me template code but the error was actually being caused by python code (that you can find in the traceback).

Ensure that `haystack` is a valid package in your Python path:

Comment out the one line that is problematic and diagnose by creating a new view function:

```
import sys
# ...
def get_sys_path(request):
    return HttpResponse(str(sys.path))
```

Add this to your `urls.py` and access it. Ensure that you can see the `haystack` directory in  one of the paths in `sys.path` (i.e. the output). If you don't see it, you've probably not installed haystack properly.